# Using secret env value in env in cloudbuild step

Tags: substitution, google-cloud-build

I have a build pipline defined as such:

```yaml
- name: 'ubuntu'
  env:
   - 'URL="$$_URL/movies"'
  secretEnv: ['_URL']
  script: 'echo URL'
availableSecrets:
 secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/url/versions/latest
    env: '_URL'
```

This produces `$_URL/movies` and I'd like to have my value substituted in that string in env. If I use single $ I get error with no default substitution called _URL.

Answer (score 2):

You have to print the env var URL in your script, like that

```
- name: 'ubuntu'
  env:
   - 'URL="$$_URL/movies"'
  secretEnv: ['_URL']
  script: 'echo $$URL'
availableSecrets:
 secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/url/versions/latest
    env: '_URL'
```

Comment: While that is true, a small mistake while creating the example. 
I resolved the issue of using secret var in `env` clause by using `script` instead and creating my more complex environment variables there.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem in the end in quite an easy way.

Using variables from secrets in clauses other than args/script is not supported, so I used only script to define variables and do computation.
I also took into account the mistake pointed out by guillaume blaquiere.

So the final yaml looks something like this:

```yaml
- name: 'ubuntu'
  env:
  secretEnv: ['_URL']
  script: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      export URL="$$_URL/movies"
      #YOU HAVE TO PUT YOUR COMPUTATION HERE, IN MY CASE:
      echo $URL
availableSecrets:
 secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/url/versions/latest
    env: '_URL'
```